# internationalization (i18n) of the square payment form (v2)

Tags: square-connect

I am currently using the square v2 form in the application to load the payment form ( script: https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform)

Is there a way to translate the labels of the form (CC, MM/YY, Card Number etc) based on the user's locale or internationalization the form

Comment: You can define the labels with javascript, so if you can detect the end user language, you should be able to customize to your needs.

Comment: Thanks!, we can use js for changing the labels. But is there a way to fetch the i18n form when locale is passed to hosted square form?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the i18n form

Comment: i18n - internationalization, I meant is there a way to get the form labels in the language of the local passed as parameter

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the term and concept, but there is not a i18n version of the form. You can change the labels client side, with JavaScript by editing the placeholders when you create a payment form object